# Starting two instances of same java process with different options using maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, pom.xml

This is what I have, which is not working. I can never see the second instance of the process running.

```
<profile>
  <id>myid</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>myid</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>first-execution</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>java</executable>
              <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.logging.file.currentLogFilename=${user.home}/logs/abc_20.log</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.http.option1=5000</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.http.option2=5001</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.option3=abc1</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.Id=abcdef1</argument>
                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                <classpath />
                <argument>com.mycompany.SomeService</argument>
                <argument>server</argument>
                <argument>dir1/config.yml</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>second-execution</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>java</executable>
              <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.logging.file.currentLogFilename=${user.home}/logs/abc_21.log</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.http.option1=6000</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.http.option2=6001</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.option3=abc2</argument>
                <argument>-Ddw.Id=abcdef2</argument>
                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                <classpath />
                <argument>com.mycompany.SomeService</argument>
                <argument>server</argument>
                <argument>dir1/config.yml</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Any help/ideas/thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you run Maven with `mvn deploy`?

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#async

Comment: @RobertScholte I think you are right.

Comment: @RobertScholte How would I use it ?? Can you please give an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the async option, you'll need to configure the plugin like this:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <async>true</async>
</configuration>
```

Also consider reading https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Parameters about how any maven plugin can be configured.